# obs-websocket-js failed to connect. Server sent no subprotocol

Tags: node.js, websocket, obs, obs-studio

I want to use [obs-websocket-js](https://github.com/obs-websocket-community-projects/obs-websocket-js) package to build an app to connect to OBS Studio through websocket.
When I try running the connection function, I get a   `Failed to connect -1 Server sent no subprotocol` error.

The OBS Studio is running on Ubuntu 20.01 which is on a Oracle VM VirtualBox on my system.

[image: Screenshot from Ubuntu subsystem]

Node.JS code:

```
const OBSWebSocket = require("obs-websocket-js").default;

const obs = new OBSWebSocket();

const connect = async () => {
  try {
     const { obsWebSocketVersion, negotiatedRpcVersion } = await obs.connect("ws://192.168.100.170:4444",undefined, {rpcVersion: 1});

    return `Connected to server ${obsWebSocketVersion} (using RPC ${negotiatedRpcVersion})`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to connect", error.code, error.message);
  }
};

connect().then((value) => console.log(value));
```

I expect to make a succesful connection and to find out why I have a Server sent no subprotocol error.

Comment: The WebSocket plugin is probably too old.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution: I **updated** the OBS Studio to the latest **29.0.0 version** and it worked.